# Responsive images for 3 different types of screens : Is this a good design?

Tags: website-design, mobile, responsive-design, responsive

[image]

Above image is a wireframe layout of my portfolio website. The navbar is at the bottom while the 2 images fill the remaining screen. The left and right picture will be contained in their own DIV (something like left picture DIV width set to 65% and right one set to 35%)

Based on this, I guess I need to prepare 3 different sets of images, one for large screens, one for mobile portrait and one for mobile landscape?

At first I was thinking just 2 sets would be enough, as large screens and mobile landscape can share the images, but then, some mobile landscape views (depending on device) have a very wide width to short height ratio, so the images won't look that good.

Comment: Just create two images one small for mobile ( max width: 600px & max-height:400) and another large for desktop. In landscape mode of mobile, you can set first image width to 65vw and height 100vh.

Answer (score 1):

Is this a good design ? Depends in what image you put there and what your requirements are.

Is this a good design methodology ? Yes and No.

**NO** - One approach is to use the same image , change the css properties (`background-size`,`background-position` etc) to make the same image fit into different dimensions. In this case you might have to make little sacrifices on the coverage of overall picture. 
A sample is https://www.uber.com/.

Careful selection of image is required in this case. Because even when a part of image is clipped of the image looks complete , at any point of time irrespective of any device.

**YES** - this depends on the requirement of the site. From your question you are building a portfolio. Speed and loading time is secondary to the UI of the site. You need to do a benefit analysis  , what do you need here better looking site or faster site. If i'm making my portfolio i would go for looks and will use different images to make it look perfect.

Comment: Tks for your reply. For the Uber site, I notice when I shrink the width, the header image is adjusted automatically such that regardless of how you shrink, the lady's face is always visible. How do they achieve this? Most of the other responsive sites with similar header images like this don't behave like Uber's.

Comment: @Xeon as said in the answer , you can play around with `background-size` and `background-position` to achieve this. I cannot give a hard value , depends on the image size, screen size and others.

Answer (score 1):

Normally we create different sized images on the basis of Responsive Breakpoints...

**Step 1)** First test by sqeezing your website from full desktop view up to iphone4 width of 320px at least

**Step 2)** Determine how many breakpoints you need

**Step 3)** Produce set of images (If needed) at least 2 or 3

**Step 4)** Only load one image for one breakpoint to optimize loading speed and time

### Few things to consider

- Apply responsive image method which loads only specific image for that specific break-point to optimize loading time e.g use [PictureFill](https://scottjehl.github.io/picturefill/#examples)
- What about Retina Images or @2x images, keep that in mind too. Use [Retina.js](http://imulus.github.io/retinajs/) for that

Comment: Tks! Will look into those.

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiple breakpoints and images for your landing page, it's the common solution used nowadays. You can also use the **srcset** attribute to define the breakpoints instead of using CSS rules. This will be better for network usage.

In this example you can see breakpoints using **srcset** at 1024px and 2048px:

```
<img 
    srcset="https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/piio-test/blog/bird-square-1024w.jpg 1024w,
            https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/piio-test/blog/bird-square-2048w.jpg 2048w"
    sizes="(max-width: 1024px) 1024px, 2048px"
    src="https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/piio-test/blog/bird-square-2048w.jpg" id="bird" />
```

The thing is that it'll require maintenance and it'll be hard to scale the solution to work on every device.

I recommend you to read this article I wrote about using Responsive Images on your website -> https://medium.com/@nicolasbistolfi/how-to-use-optimized-responsive-images-aa6b9452e6ce

Comment: could you copy and paste some the relevant information into your answer?

Comment: I added an example on how to use srcet on an image with breakpoints

Comment: You're giving a development solution as opposed to a UX one.The question is not how to create a breakpoint but on the design scheme.